# Postgresql readonly role and user

Tags: postgresql, readonly

I couldn't find an answer to this question: why does selecting from the table fail after the privileges were granted?

```
-- create new role
CREATE ROLE readonly;

-- grant access to all existing tables
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE shop TO readonly;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO readonly;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readonly;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO readonly;
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO readonly;

-- grant access to all table which will be created in the future
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonly;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON SEQUENCES TO readonly;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS TO readonly;

-- create user and grant role to this user
CREATE USER b_readonly WITH PASSWORD 'reAdOnLy123';
GRANT readonly TO b_readonly;
```

My error message from db is following:

> ERROR:  permission denied for relation customer_search_query SQL
> state: 42501

Is there some new trick in Postgresql 9.6.5?

Comment: To rule out the obvious: is the table `customer_search_query` in the schema `public` or is it maybe created in a different schema on the search path?

Answer (score 4):

If pg version < 14
try as:

```
postgres=# CREATE ROLE readaccess;
postgres=# CREATE USER read_user WITH PASSWORD 'read_password';
postgres=# GRANT readaccess TO read_user;
    
--- INPORTANT (select needed db)---
postgres=# \с your_db;
your_db=# GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE your_db TO readaccess;
your_db=# GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readaccess;
```

if pg version >= 14

```
 GRANT pg_read_all_data TO readaccess;
```

Comment: `pg_read_all_data` should also work with Postgresql 14 but I haven't tried it. [Related document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/predefined-roles.html)

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that the table you're querying from, `customer_search_query` is not in the public schema. Try running this command.

```
GRANT SELECT ON customer_search_query TO readonly;
```